# Getting Knockout Binding to work with Appframework

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, appframework

I am developing an appframework based mobile application using  knockout js for data binding.

I keep getting the following error message on my browser console :

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: technology_name is not defined;
>   Bindings value: text: technology_name, click: $parent.loadSubSection

I can verify that the data is loaded but the knockout binding doesn't seem to work properly. Could anyone please help me out ?. My code is like follows :

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <!--
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/cordova/cordova.js"></script>
    -->

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <title>Our Workplace</title>

    <!-- Loading the Appframework Libraries -->

    <!-- Appframework Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/appframework.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/android.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/win8.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/bb.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/ios.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/ios7.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/badges.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/buttons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/lists.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/forms.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/css/src/grid.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/plugins/css/af.actionsheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/plugins/css/af.popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/appframework/plugins/css/af.selectBox.css" />

    <!-- Appframework Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/appframework.js"></script>

    <!-- Google maps plugin -->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&language=en"></script>-->

    <script>

        function loadedPanel(what) {
            //We are going to set the badge as the number of li elements inside the target
            $.ui.updateBadge("#aflink", $("#af").find("li").length);
        }


        function unloadedPanel(what) {
            console.log("unloaded " + what.id);
        }

        if (!((window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) || 'ontouchstart' in window)) {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = "libs/appframework/plugins/af.desktopBrowsers.js";
            var tag = $("head").append(script);
        }


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.actionsheet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.css3animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.passwordBox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.scroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.selectBox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.touchEvents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.touchLayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.popup.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/ui/src/appframework.ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/ui/transitions/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/appframework/plugins/af.slidemenu.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* This function runs once the page is loaded, but appMobi is not yet active */
        //$.ui.animateHeaders=false;
        var search = document.location.search.toLowerCase().replace("?", "");
        //if(!search)
        //$.os.useOSThemes=false;

        if (search) //Android fix has too many buggy issues on iOS - can't preview with $.os.android
        {

            $.os.useOSThemes = true;
            if (search == "win8")
                $.os.ie = true;
            $.ui.ready(function () {
                $("#afui").get(0).className = search;
            });
        }

        var webRoot = "./";
        // $.os.android=true;
        $.ui.autoLaunch = false;
        $.ui.openLinksNewTab = false;
        //$.ui.resetScrollers=false;


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ui.launch();

        });

        /* This code is used to run as soon as appMobi activates */
        var onDeviceReady = function () {
            AppMobi.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");
            AppMobi.device.setAutoRotate(false);
            webRoot = AppMobi.webRoot + "";
            //hide splash screen
            AppMobi.device.hideSplashScreen();
            $.ui.blockPageScroll(); //block the page from scrolling at the header/footer

        };
        document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function showHide(obj, objToHide) {
            var el = $("#" + objToHide)[0];

            if (obj.className == "expanded") {
                obj.className = "collapsed";
            } else {
                obj.className = "expanded";
            }
            $(el).toggle();

        }


        if ($.os.android || $.os.ie || search == "android") {
            $.ui.ready(function () {
                $("#main .list").append("<li><a id='toggleAndroidTheme'>Toggle Theme Color</a></li>");
                var $el = $("#afui");
                $("#toggleAndroidTheme").bind("click", function (e) {
                    if ($el.hasClass("light"))
                        $el.removeClass("light");
                    else
                        $el.addClass("light");
                });
            });
        }
    </script>



    <style>
        .samplecode {
            background: #ccc;
            color: #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        /* for the grid demo */
        .grid > div {
            border: 1px dashed black;
        }
    </style>


    <!-- Loading JQuery Libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.core/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log("Resolved JQUERY Conflicts...");
    </script>


    <!-- Loading Knockout js content -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/knockoutjs/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/knockoutjs/mapping/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

    <!-- Loading View Models -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="logic/technology.js"></script>

      </head>
      <body>
       <div id="afui" class="">
        <!-- this is the splashscreen you see. -->
        <div id="splashscreen" class='ui-loader heavy'>
                     App Framework

            <br>
            <br>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading spin'></span>
            <h1>Starting app</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <a id='menubadge' onclick='af.ui.toggleSideMenu()' class='menuButton'></a>
        </div>


        <!-- this is the splashscreen you see. -->
        <div id="Div2" class='ui-loader heavy'>
            Our WorkPlace
                <br>
            <br>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading spin'></span>
            <h1>Loading Data...</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div title='Our Workplace' id="main" class="panel" selected="true" data-load="loadedPanel" data-unload="unloadedPanel" data-tab="navbar_home">

                <div class="dash-widgts">
                    <p class="dashboard-icons">
                        <a>
                            <img src="images/main_menu/icon-our-workplace.png" alt="" /></a>

                        <a class="evn">
                            <img src="images/main_menu/icon-building-essentials.png" alt="" /></a>

                        <a href="#technologyMain" data-transition="slide" title="Technology">
                            <img src="images/main_menu/icon-technology.png" alt="" /></a>

                        <a class="evn">
                            <img src="images/main_menu/icon-help.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <a>
                            <img src="images/main_menu/icon-whats-on.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="evn" href="templates/idea/idea_suggesstion.html">
                            <img src="images/main_menu/icon-idea.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>





        </div><!--/conent -->

         <div title="Technology" id="technologyMain" class="panel">
                <span id="Span1">Technology Inner</span>
                 <ul  id="technologyItems" class="list">
                    <li>
                        <a data-bind="text: technology_name, click: $parent.loadSubSection"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Technology.js Javascript file**

```
    /** The technology related view model*/
 //console.log("Self Initialised the page...");
var viewModel = new TechnologyViewModel();  ;
(function(){

    jQuery(document).on("pageinit", function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        console.log("Bound technology View Model...");
    });

 })();


 //Technology View Model
 function TechnologyViewModel(){
    self = this;

     /*Functon Loading the Technology Subsection By Id*/
     self.loadSubSection = function(technologyItem) {


            var subSectionid = parseInt(technologyItem.technology_item_id);     
            switch (subSectionid)
            {             

               case 1:  
               localStorage.clear();
               localStorage.setItem('technology_object', JSON.stringify(technologyItem));
              // $.mobile.changePage("working_wirelessly.html",{transition: 'slide'});
               break;

               case 2:  
               localStorage.clear();
               localStorage.setItem('technology_object', JSON.stringify(technologyItem));         
              // $.mobile.changePage("printer_setup.html",{transition: 'slide'});
               break;

               case 3:
               localStorage.clear();
               localStorage.setItem('technology_object', JSON.stringify(technologyItem));
              // $.mobile.changePage("mobile_hotspot.html",{transition: 'slide'});
               break;

               case 4:
               localStorage.clear();
               localStorage.setItem('technology_object', JSON.stringify(technologyItem));
               //$.mobile.changePage("blackberry_z10.html",{transition: 'slide'});
               break;

              case 5:
               localStorage.clear();
               localStorage.setItem('technology_object', JSON.stringify(technologyItem));
               //$.mobile.changePage("desk_phone.html",{transition: 'slide'});
              break;

        }
     }


    /*
    Function For Fetching all the 'Technology' Specific data    
    */      
    self.fetchScreenData = ko.computed(function(){
        console.log("Getting Technology Screen Data From File");

        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",            
                url: "data/Appdata.json", 
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS: ");
                        /*
                        Parsing Raw data to JSON
                        */
                        var data = JSON.parse(result);

                        /*
                         Map only  the [app basic] and the [technology]
                         array content to the screen
                        */
                        var mapping = { 'observe': ["app_basic","technology"] };                    
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data,mapping,self);

                        /*
                         Function fetching the Technology Screen Header
                        */
                        self.getTechScreenHeader =  ko.dependentObservable(function() {

                             return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.app_basic(), function(appScreen) {
                                     return appScreen.app_screen_id == 3;
                                });

                        }, self);   
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error loading app json data");
                }
        });

        console.log("GOT Technology Screen Data From File");
    },self);



}
```

Also I am using the following JSON file to load the json data and map them automagically using the knockout-mapping plugin.

```
  "technology" : [
      {
         "technology_description" : "Bla"
         "technology_item_id" : "1",
         "technology_name" : "bla bla",
         "technology_subject" : "bla bla",
         "technology_video_desc" : "null",
         "technology_video_link" : "null",
         "technology_video_thumbnail" : "null"
      },
        {
         "technology_description" : "Bla"
         "technology_item_id" : "2",
         "technology_name" : "bla bla",
         "technology_subject" : "bla bla",
         "technology_video_desc" : "null",
         "technology_video_link" : "null",
         "technology_video_thumbnail" : "null"
      },
        {
         "technology_description" : "Bla"
         "technology_item_id" : "3",
         "technology_name" : "bla bla",
         "technology_subject" : "bla bla",
         "technology_video_desc" : "null",
         "technology_video_link" : "null",
         "technology_video_thumbnail" : "null"
      },

   ],
```

I am just using the standard index.html configuration found on the appframework itself for importing the headers.

Comment: Where are you getting the technology_name from?  I don't see any observables in your view model at all.

Comment: I am getting that mapped using the knockout mapping plugin from a json data file. I have added the sample json data file I am using.

Comment: I don't mean this to sound rude, but just for my understanding have you used Knockout before?  You seem to be missing some some markup.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example at home if you still needing this. As i couldn't find one i made it work myself. I can post it later.

Comment: I'll give you an answer later - is not an answer.